# How to test `font-lock-keywords` values for Emacs Lisp code

Tags: regex, emacs, elisp, syntax-highlighting, font-lock

I pose the question because I think both the question and possible answers might help Emacs users who write Lisp code that defines `font-lock-keywords`.  I'm providing one answer that I think helps.  I'm also interested in other answers.

That variable's value is a list of expressions, each of which can specify one or more patterns to match or functions to perform matching, and one or more faces for highlighting the matching text.  The possibilities for `font-lock-keywords` values are numerous and complicated. (The doc describing this is the Elisp manual, node [`Search-based Fontification`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Search_002dbased-Fontification.html#Search_002dbased-Fontification).)

In most cases the list has more than one element, which means more than one regexp pattern.  These can interact in different ways.  Some can prevent others from taking effect, or they can alter the effect of others.  My library [**Dired+**](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/DiredPlus), for instance, defines `font-lock-keywords` in Dired mode with 31 entries (regexps), many of which interact.

*How to keep all of that straight?*  How do ***you*** debug such a list when you are defining it or modifying it?  You might comment out all but one of the list items, to see its effect when alone.  And then repeat for another.  And then perhaps add a few together, and maybe in different orders.  There are various possibilities, I suppose, but just what do you do?

(OK, I know that most Elisp coders do not write super complex `font-lock-keywords` definitions.  But even for simple definitions this can become complicated.  And perhaps if this process were easier then users would not unnecessarily limit themselves to only one or two entries.)

Comment: I asked myself the same question a couple of weeks ago, having written several font-lock packages, but found no good answer. So, I started writing an interactive font-lock debugger where you can single step through the font-lock keywords and it visualizes the match in the debugger and source buffers. I haven't finished it just yet, but I will release it in due course. While waiting, you can take a look at my regression test system for font-lock keywords: https://github.com/Lindydancer/faceup

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use my newly released [Font Lock Studio](https://github.com/Lindydancer/font-lock-studio). The following is from the readme-file:

## font-lock-studio - interactive debugger for Font Lock keywords

*Font Lock Studio* is an *interactive debugger* for Font Lock
keywords (Emacs syntax highlighting rules).

### Introduction

Font Lock Studio lets you *single-step* Font Lock keywords --
matchers, highlights, and anchored rules, so that you can see what
happens when a buffer is fontified. You can set *breakpoints* on or
inside rules and *run* until one has been hit. When inside a rule,
matches are *visualized* using a palette of background colors. The
*explainer* can describe a rule in plain-text english. Tight
integration with *Edebug* allows you to step into Lisp expressions
that are part of the Font Lock keywords.

When using the debugger, an *interface buffer* is displayed, it
contains all the keywords and is used for navigation and
visalization of match data.

When Font Lock Studio is started, comments and strings are
pre-colored, as they are part of the earlier *syntactic phase*
(which isn't supported by Font Lock Studio).

Start the debugger by typing "M-x font-lock-studio RET". Press `?`
or see the menu for available commands.

### Example

For a buffer using `html-mode`, the interface buffer looks the
following. Other major modes typically have more and more complex
rules. The arrow on the left indicates the current active location.
A corresponding arrow in the source buffer is placed at the current
search location.

```
        ========================
        === Font Lock Studio ===
        ========================
    --------------------------------------------------
=>  "<\\([!?][_:[:alpha:]][-_.:[:alnum:]]*\\)"
      (1 font-lock-keyword-face)
    --------------------------------------------------
    "</?\\([_[:alpha:]][-_.[:alnum:]]*\\)\\(?::\\([_:[:alpha:]]
    [-_.:[:alnum:]]*\\)\\)?"
      (1
       (if
           (match-end 2)
           sgml-namespace-face font-lock-function-name-face))
      (2 font-lock-function-name-face nil t)
    --------------------------------------------------
    "\\(?:^\\|[ \t]\\)\\([_[:alpha:]][-_.[:alnum:]]*\\)\\(?::
    \\([_:[:alpha:]][-_.:[:alnum:]]*\\)\\)?=[\"']"
      (1
       (if
           (match-end 2)
           sgml-namespace-face font-lock-variable-name-face))
      (2 font-lock-variable-name-face nil t)
    --------------------------------------------------
    "[&%][_:[:alpha:]][-_.:[:alnum:]]*;?"
      (0 font-lock-variable-name-face)
    --------------------------------------------------
    "<\\(b\\(?:ig\\|link\\)\\|cite\\|em\\|h[1-6]\\|rev\\|s\\(?:
    mall\\|trong\\)\\|t\\(?:itle\\|t\\)\\|var\\|[bisu]\\)
    \\([ \t][^>]*\\)?>\\([^<]+\\)</\\1>"
      (3
       (cdr
        (assoc-string
         (match-string 1)
         sgml-tag-face-alist t))
       prepend)
    ==================================================
    Public state:
      Debug on error     : YES
      Debug on quit      : YES
      Explain rules      : YES
      Show compiled code : NO
```

Press space to single step through all the keywords. "n" will go
the the next keyword, "b" will set a breakpoint, "g" will run to
the end (or to the next breakpoint) and "q" will quit.

### Features

#### Stepping

You can single *step into*, *over*, and *out* of Font Lock
keywords. *Anchored* rules are fully supported. In addition, you
can *run* to the end or to the next breakpoint.

#### Breakpoints

You can set breakpoints on part of the keyword, like the matcher
(e.g. the regexp), a highlight rule, or inside an anchored highlight
rule.

If you want to step or run without stopping on breakpoints, prefix
the command with `C-u`.

Note that in an anchored rule, you can set a breakpoints either on
the entire rule or on an individual part. In the former case, only
the outer parentheses are highlighted.

#### Match Data Visualization

After the *matcher* of a keyword or anchored highlight has been
executed, the match data (whatever the search found) is visualized
using background colors in the source buffer, in the regexp, and
over the corresponding highlight rule or rules. If part of a regexp
or a highlight didn't match, it is not colored, this can for
example happen when the postfix regexp operator `?` is used.

Note that an inner match group gets precedence over an outer group.
This can lead to situations where a highlight rule gets a color
that doesn't appear in the regexp or in the source buffer. For
example, the matcher "\(abc\)" will be colored with the color for
match 1, while the higlight rule `(0 a-face)' gets the color for
match 0.

#### Normalized keywords

The keywords presented in the interface have been normalized. For
example, instead of

```
     ("xyz" . font-lock-type-face)
```

the keyword

```
      ("xyz" (0 font-lock-type-face))
```

is shown. See `font-lock-studio-normalize-keywords` for details.

#### Explainer

The *explainer* echoes a human-readble description of the current
part of the Font Lock keywords. This help you to understand that
all those `nil`:s and `t`:s in the rules actually mean.

When using the *auto explainer*, Font Lock Studio echoes the
explanation after each command.

#### Edebug -- the Emacs Lisp debugger

Tight integration with Edebug allows you to single-step expressions
embedded in the keywords in the interface buffer, and it allows you
to instrument called functions for debugging in their source file.

#### Follow mode awareness

The search location in the source buffer is visualized by an
overlay arrow and by updating the point. If the source buffer is
visible in multiple side-by-side windows and Follow mode is
enabled, the search location will be shown in a suitable windows to
minimize scrolling.

Comment: Sounds useful, and the code looks good. You obviously put a lot of work into it.  (Haven't tried it yet.)  You might want to mention which Emacs versions it is compatible with, in the file header. Experimenting, I can see that Emacs prior to 24.3 will not work, because of `user-error`, for instance.  If you changed a few such gratuitous novelties you could no doubt easily make it usable with multiple Emacs versions -- if you wanted to.  Anyway, it looks like a welcome addition. Maybe consider adding mention of it on [EmacsWiki](http://www.emacswiki.org/) (e.g., create a page for it).

Comment: Ah, I see that you do address the Emacs version question in the file header, after all.

Comment: FYI, I tried it briefly using Emacs 24.3, in the file's own buffer. I stepped once with `SPC` and it moved to `lambda`. I stepped a second time with `SPC` and Emacs crashed. Since it was Emacs 24.3, there was no file `emacs_backtrace.txt` generated. Anyway, I will play with it some more. An Emacs crash is not the code's fault, but rather an Emacs bug somewhere.

Comment: FYI (and I'll sign off after this): I tried the same thing with a recent Emacs Dev snapshot (pre-24.4), and no crash: `lambda` was replaced by the Unicode symbol (per my font-lock keywords), without problem.

Comment: Looks very good so far. I'll accept this as the best answer.  One thing I'd like to see (is it possible already?) is the ability to show what it shows for a given instance of a keyword for all such matches at the same time. IOW: show the highlighting for all matches for a given keyword (or any of its parts).  So far, it seems to only show one hit at time --- very much like a debugger.  If that is not possible, then this would appear to be **complementary** to the **`icicle-font-lock-keywords`** answer I gave.

Comment: @Drew, as you saw, with the help of the side package `anders-old-emacs-support' you can use it with Emacs 22 and newer. It looks like I have stumbled upon an Emacs bug, when binding `standard-output' to a function sometimes garbage comes out (this could account for the crash) -- see bug#16576. I will publish a new version with a workaround as soon as I have tested it properly. I will take a look at the icicle package and see if I can add some kind of "highlight all" thing. Thanks for your feedback!

Comment: @Drew, if you give the "n" command `font-lock-studio-next-keyword' it will fontify all occurrences of the current keyword. I realize now that if you only would like to apply one you would have to repeat "i n" (ignore keyword) until you get to the one you want. Maybe I will make the ignore command stop of breakpoints as well, that way you could set a breakpoint, do "ignore run" (which currently doesn't exist) and "n" to fontify. Would that work for your scenario?

Comment: I don't really have a scenario.  What `icicle-font-lock-keywords` lets you do is activate individual font-lock entries and sets of entries, to see their effects (individual or set).  IOW, you can easily see the effect of different combinations of font-lock entries.  AFAICT, that is a complementary feature to what your font-lock debugger provides. But maybe I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Well, it depends on the command you are using. On one hand you can step into a keyword. However, you can also step to the next keyword using "n", when you do the full effect of the current keyword is applied at once. I have no way of defining a "set" of keywords, but you can get a similar effect by skipping the keywords you don't want with "i n" and fontify the ones you want with "n". Also, I just added a "goto keyword" command so you more easily could just pick a rule to run.

Answer (score 0):

To help with this problem, I coded up an [**Icicles**](http://www.emacswiki.org/cgi-bin/wiki/Icicles) [multi-command](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Multi-Commands), **`icicle-font-lock-keywords`**.  It lets you do things like the following:

- Cycle among the separate `font-lock-keywords` entries (patterns), applying them individually to see the effect of each alone.
- Pick individual entries and apply them separately, to see the same thing.
- Pick a **set** of entries and apply it, in the same order the entries appear in `font-lock-keywords`.  You can do this for any number of sets.
- Accumulate the effect of multiple sets of entries, in the order you choose them.
- Revert, to see the effect of all entries together, i.e., all of `font-lock-keywords`.

And you can do all of that, in any order, in a single invocation of the command.

`M-o` is the prefix key for Facemenu and font-locking, so I put this command on key **`M-o I`**, when in *Icicle* mode.

Comment: When looking how to download at http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Libraries, can't see an archive.

Comment: @AndreasRöhler - sorry, I don't know what you mean. There are several ways to get the Icicles files, including from MELPA.  What did you try, and what problem did you have?