# How to add extra font lock to comment face

Tags: elisp, font-lock

I want to differentiate comments.
In elisp mode, I want to have `string` in `;;! string` highlighted.

```
(font-lock-add-keywords 'emacs-lisp-mode
                        '((";;!\\(.*\\)\\\n" 0 'my-important-comment-face)))
```

However, it is not effective.

Answer (score 0):

This question:
[How to test `font-lock-keywords` values for Emacs Lisp code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21125658/how-to-test-font-lock-keywords-values-for-emacs-lisp-code?rq=1)
will point you at some tools that might help you to trace why your code is not being effective.